# String list with split

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string and a string list. I am trying to return a list that whatever strList is contains in str, the result should be 4 and 21.

Here is my code, not sure what I am missing.

```
string str= "21,1,4";
List<string> strList= new List<string> { "4","21" };

var a = str.Where(i => i.ToString().Split(new char[] { ',' },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList().Any(s=>strList.Contains(s)));
```

Comment: The call to `ToString()` i `(i => i.ToString()` is redundant....it's already a string.

Comment: A good troubleshooting technique is to break the operations up into pieces. Maybe split the string in a separate step so when you step through the debugger, you can see all the pieces easier.

Comment: @Tim Calling `.ToList()` on the array that `.Split()` returns is also unnecessary for the `.Any()` operation.

Comment: @Tim.  No, `i` is a `char` because `str` is a `string`.  So the call is not redundant, it's just that iterating over the `char`s in `str` doesn't make sense here.

Comment: @juharr - Yep, you're correct.  I didn't catch that, but it makes sense given the `Where`.

Answer (score 4):

```
    string str = "21,1,4";
    List<string> strList = new List<string> { "4", "21" };
    var splitStr = str.Split(',');
    var result = splitStr.Where(x => strList.Contains(x));
```

Comment: `Where (x => strList.Contains (x))` can be reduced to just `Where (strList.Contains)` (by eta-conversion)

Comment: @Sehnsucht I don't know we can write by that format. Thank you for your sharing

Answer (score 1):

```
string str= "21,1,4";
List<string> strList= new List<string> { "4","21" };
string[] result = str.Split(',');

foreach(string s in result)
   if(strList.Contains(s))
      Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Make it simple.

Answer (score 1):

To keep it all on one line, which seems to be your goal:

```
string str = "21,1,4";
List<string> strList = new List<string> { "4", "21" };

var a = str.Split(',').Where(s => strList.Contains(s));
```

`a` will be an IEnumerable of all values in str (after splitting) that are contained in `strList`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `Intersect`

```
string str = "21,1,4";
List<string> strList = new List<string> { "4", "21" };
var result = str.Split(',').Intersect(strList);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));
```

Output:

> 21, 4

The issue with your code is that by doing `str.Where` you are iterating over the characters of the string.  You should instead just split `str` then iterate over that to find the matches in `strList`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
string str = "21,1,4";
List<string> strList = new List<string> { "4", "21" };

List<string> splitList = str.Split(",").ToList();

List<string> overlap = strList.Where(str => splitList.Contains(str)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        var str = "21,1,4";
        var otherStrList = new List<string> { "4", "21" };
        var separatedstrList = str.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
        var commonStrings = separatedstrList.Intersect(otherStrList);
```

where `commonStrings` is the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

How about an elegant Join syntax:

```
var results = (from main in str.Split(',')
                join key in strList
                on main equals key
                select main).ToList();
```

you may add `.Distinct()` before `.ToList()` if you want to remove duplicates (if `str` has duplicates).